# Matlab: What are the ways to determine the distribution of the data

Tags: matlab, statistics, distribution

I have a data set of n = 1000 realizations of a random variable X and is univariate -- `X = {x1, x2,...,xn}`. Data is generated by varying a parameter on which the random variable depends. For example, let the r.v be Area of a circle. So, by varying the radius (keeping the dimension fixed - say 2 dimensional circle) I generate `n` area for radius in the range `r = 5 to n`.

By using [fitdist](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitdist.html) command I can fit distribution to the data set choosing distributions like Normal, Kernel, Binomial etc. Thus, data set is fitted to k distribution. So, I get k distributions. How do I select the Best fit distribution and hence the pdf ?

Also, do I need to normalize (post process) the data always in the range [0,1] before fitting?

Comment: I don't have a strong background to address some of your questions, but I can recommend this submission, which should give you some directions to look into:  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34943-fit-all-valid-parametric-probability-distributions-to-data/content/allfitdist.m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are asking how to decide which distribution to choose once you have a few fits.

There are three major metrics (IMO) for measuring "goodness-of-fit":

- [Chi-Squared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodness_of_fit)
- [Kolmogrov-Smirnov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test)
- [Anderson-Darling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anderson%E2%80%93Darling_test)

Which to choose depends on a large number of factors; you can randomly pick one or read the Wiki pages to figure out which suits your need. These tests are also a part of MATLAB.

For instance, you can use [`kstest`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kstest.html) for the Kolmogrov-Smirnov test. You can provide the data and the hypothesized distribution to the function and evaluate the different options based on the KS test.

Alternately, you can use Anderson-Darling through [`adtest`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/adtest.html) or Chi-Squared through [`chi2gof`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/chi2gof.html).

Comment: 3 Questions, if you may please clarify - (a) For different SNR, I have a data set of n realizations of the r.v. X. Do I need to fit distribution to each of the data set for their corresponding SNR? If so, then how will I get a pdf that encapsulates the noisy data for all SNR? What is the correct procedure? (b) The values of the data set are not in any range bound. The min(data) =  5.2931 and max(data)= 2.4854e+005. So, is it a practice to standardize / normalize the data to [0,1] before fitting?

Comment: (c)For the case of multivariate data, how do I use histfit() or other methods because histfit (fitting by histogram) only accepts a vector ? Can you share some insights, please?

Comment: @SKM, (b) I wouldn't do any normalization. The whole point of fitting a distribution is to see trends and tails; if you standardize data not only are you implicitly forcing a distribution but are also corrupting the true nature of the spread. (c) You can use [MLE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/mle.html) for fitting distributions. For (a), I have no insight; I'm not an expert in signal processing.